# CUDA is installed but GPU is not being used

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I have python 3. I have installed CUDA 10, Tensorflow-gpu, and Keras. My code still uses CPU. The error:

```
2019-10-30 16:20:08.873984: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 AVX512F FMA
2019-10-30 16:20:08.885799: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2019-10-30 16:20:08.889181: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:318] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is detected
2019-10-30 16:20:08.889217: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: exec-gpu02
2019-10-30 16:20:08.889225: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: exec-gpu02
2019-10-30 16:20:08.889280: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:200] libcuda reported version is: 418.39.0
2019-10-30 16:20:08.889310: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:204] kernel reported version is: 418.39.0
2019-10-30 16:20:08.889316: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:310] kernel version seems to match DSO: 418.39.0
2019-10-30 16:20:08.897876: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2100000000 Hz
2019-10-30 16:20:08.900844: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x3f13fb0 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2019-10-30 16:20:08.900866: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
```

How can I get it fixed?

Comment: try: ```pip install tensorflow-gpu```, and make sure you have the CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES environment variable set correctly. If those two don't work, I don't know what to do without more information.

Comment: @TomC Thanks. Then tensorflow-gpu has been already installed. Can you please let me know how I can make sure CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES environment variable has been set correctly?

Comment: try ```import os; os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = "" ``` at the top of your python script. Make sure tensorflow can see your GPU by doing ```import tensorflow as tf; tf.test.is_gpu_available()```.

Comment: Are you willing to install it the hard way (build from source)? It's how I did it - works as intended. The official guide is a bit off, but I recall my exact steps. Also, if you use Anaconda, install via `conda`, _not_ `pip`. Lastly, some further info would help: (1) IDE (Visual Studio, Spyder, ...); (2) package manager (pip, Anaconda, ...); (3) GPU; (4) Python version (3.x); (5) which version of TF do you plan on using?

Comment: Seconding to use conda instead of pip, if you're using a conda environment. Also check to make sure that you have an up-to-date driver installed. If you run `nvidia-smi`, what happens?